# Unable to remove a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove a div by clicking other div.
For example by clicking anywhere in the `close` div, i want to remove the `content` div. Here's what I'm trying and not working:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="close">close</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#close').click(function () {
   $('#content').fadeOut(200, function () { $(this).remove()})
});
```

**Error:**

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

void;
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/p6qrB/

Comment: That's because you haven't loaded jQuery in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j8C83/

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not notice that. I thought it includes jQuery by default.

Comment: strange you test your code in jsfiddle instead of your machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You just forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p6qrB/1/

Comment: Thanks and sorry. I thought it includes jQuery by default.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to include jQuery in your JSFiddle. You have included MooTools instead which is another JS lib.

Here is a working jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/p6qrB/2/